# How can I say "in the long run"?

Tags: translation

The expression *in the long run* is used when talking about long-term consequences.

- We will profit from it in the long run.
- I'm sure it's the best solution in the long run.
- In the long run, this misstake will not seem so devastating.

What can I say in Esperanto?

Comment: "In the long run, we are all dead" – Keynes. SCNR.

Answer (score 5):

Vi povas diri **postlonge** aŭ **je longa daŭro**.

Ekzemple:

> Honesto profitigas je longa daŭro. [Honesty pays in the long run.]

> Viaj klopodoj estos kompensitaj postlonge. [Your effort will be rewarded in the long run.]

Ne gravas kiun vi elektas uzi.

Answer (score 0):

I would say *En la daŭro de la tempo*.

Variations of this found in the Tekstaro include:

- En la daŭro de tiu ĉi tempo
- En la daŭro de tiu tempo
- en la daŭro de tre longa tempo
- en la daŭro de kelka tempo
- en la daŭro de longa tempo

Of course there's also *finfine* - often glossed as "at long last."